# Applying a pantone color to a font in iText7

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm evaluating if iText7 is good enough to use in a future project.

Can someone provide me with a clear example on iText7 on how to create and apply a pantone color to a font?

I used to develop on another PDF library and in that case, I would supply the "R G B H S B" values into an array, create my colorspace and then use this colorspace everywhere. I can't seem to do this on itext7.

I want to write a font on a pdf using pantone color "PANTONE 485 C" with the following values of RGB HSB:

- H: 255
- S: 251
- B: 248
- R: 220
- G: 36
- B: 31

Most of the examples I find is for iText5 (functions and classes that have been removed in iText7)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If this is a commercial project, get in touch with your local iText sales office. They'll be happy to set you up with trial licenses, and you'd be able to ask your questions directly to iText developers.

Comment: I have a trial license, as I'm only evaluating if this serves my purpose.

I was told to ask my questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: That seems strange. Could you tell me what company you've requested this license for? Then I can ask our sales team for more information.

Comment: Let me be more clear on what I said before. Nobody from the support/sales team told me to ask in stackoverflow. The website hints into doing that if my answer has not been answered in stackoverflow. If a trial user can contact itext developers, I would like to know how as it would be much faster.

Comment: If you are testing this with the goal of evaluating commercial viability, you can contact our sales team. They'll set everything up for you. Including access to our Jira ticketing system.
If you go to http://itextpdf.com/ and scroll down, you should see the list of all sales offices. Simply contact the one in your region.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will eventually post their answer here.

Answer (score 1):

To use a Pantone color in PDF it should be defined as a Separation color space.

```cs
string dest = @"C:\publish\Pantone.pdf";
string text = "This text is PANTONE 485 C.";
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create))
{
    var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(fileStream));
    using (var doc = new Document(pdfDoc))
    {
        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);

        var alternateSpace = new DeviceRgb(220, 36, 31);
        var tintTransform = new PdfFunction.Type2(
            new PdfArray(new[] { 0.0f, 1f }),
            null,
            new PdfArray(new[] { 1f, 1f, 1f }),
            new PdfArray(new[] { alternateSpace.GetColorValue()[0], alternateSpace.GetColorValue()[1], alternateSpace.GetColorValue()[2] }),
            new PdfNumber(1f));

        var pantone = new Separation("PANTONE 485 C", alternateSpace.GetColorSpace(), tintTransform, 1f);
        doc.Add(new Paragraph(text).SetFontColor(pantone).SetFont(font).SetFontSize(12f));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is C# method for creating a RGB spot color

```
using iText.Kernel.Colors;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Function;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
private Separation SpotColor(string name, int r,int g,int b)
{
    var alternateSpace = new DeviceRgb(r, g, b);
    var tintTransform = new PdfFunction.Type2(
        new PdfArray(new[] { 0.0f, 1f }),
        null,
        new PdfArray(new[] { 1f, 1f, 1f }),
        new PdfArray(new[] { alternateSpace.GetColorValue()[0], alternateSpace.GetColorValue()[1], alternateSpace.GetColorValue()[2]}),
        new PdfNumber(1f));

    var spot = new Separation(name, alternateSpace.GetColorSpace(), tintTransform, 1f);
    return spot;
}
```

Then you can use this method to add a spot color to your canvas like in this code. I am setting up a spot color for perf cuts which for many cutters requres the spot color to be called "CutContourPerf", using an RGB of red

```
iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
canvas.SetStrokeColor(SpotColor("CutContourPerf", 255, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this java snippet lying around.
The mapping to C# should be fairly good.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // color definition
    Color color = new DeviceRgb(220,36,31);

    // set up IO
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "stackoverflow.pdf"));
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document doc = new Document(pdf);

    // add paragraph in desired color
    Paragraph para = new Paragraph("I want to write a font on a pdf using pantone color \"PANTONE 485 C\" with the following values of RGB HSB");
    para.setFontColor(color);
    doc.add(para);

    // close IO
    doc.flush();
    doc.close();
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply.

You are adding an RGB color and not a Pantone Color. That will not work with the printers.

It needs to be detected a "Separation color" on Acrobat Pro.

I saw an itext7 example where someone did this on a circular shape. But I cannot apply this spot color to a font.

Comment: I could be mistaken (given that my knowledge of color spaces is limited), but given the fact that there is a way to map RGB to HSB and vice versa), the second pair of values seems rather uncalled for.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB